# Why does Test::MockObject make thawing my objects throw warnings?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, storable

This one needs a bit of explanation to start with. I've got a unit test where I save [Class::Std::Fast::Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class%3a%3aStd%3a%3aFast%3a%3aStorable) objects that come from [SOAP::WSDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL) using [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable). The object I am storing is the result of a webservice call. It ends up being encoded with [MIME::Base64](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME%3a%3aBase64) and written somewhere to a file. This is working great.

When I was building up the unit test, I needed to use [Test::MockObject](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test%3a%3aMockObject) to mock the call that webservice, thus returning the restored object. But somehow this is throwing a bunch of warnings about the *use of uninitialized value in hash element*.

I tried recreating it as a small example. This first bit of code is how I get the base64 output for the example. We will use it in a minute.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64;
use Storable;
use SOAP::WSDL::XSD::Typelib::Builtin::anySimpleType;

my $object = SOAP::WSDL::XSD::Typelib::Builtin::anySimpleType->new;
$object->set_value('foo');
print encode_base64(Storable::freeze($object));
```

So we got three lines of base64. Let's try to restore them:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64;
use Storable;
use Test::Simple tests => 1;

local $/ = undef;
my $object = Storable::thaw(decode_base64(<DATA>));
ok( $object->get_value, 'foo' );

__DATA__
BAgIMTIzNDU2NzgECAgIE0ADAQAAAAQDAQAAAAoDZm9vBQAAAHZhbHVlMAAAAFNPQVA6OldTREw6
OlhTRDo6VHlwZWxpYjo6QnVpbHRpbjo6YW55U2ltcGxlVHlwZYAwU09BUDo6V1NETDo6WFNEOjpU
eXBlbGliOjpCdWlsdGluOjphbnlTaW1wbGVUeXBlEAQICDEyMzQ1Njc4BAgICAUBAAAAAQ==
```

Neat. It works!

```
~> perl foo.t
1..1
ok 1 - foo
```

Now let's add Test::MockObject.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64;
use Storable;
use Test::Simple tests => 1;
use Test::MockObject; # <------- only line I changed

local $/ = undef;
my $object = Storable::thaw(decode_base64(<DATA>));
ok( $object->get_value, 'foo' );

__DATA__
BAgIMTIzNDU2NzgECAgIE0ADAQAAAAQDAQAAAAoDZm9vBQAAAHZhbHVlMAAAAFNPQVA6OldTREw6
OlhTRDo6VHlwZWxpYjo6QnVpbHRpbjo6YW55U2ltcGxlVHlwZYAwU09BUDo6V1NETDo6WFNEOjpU
eXBlbGliOjpCdWlsdGluOjphbnlTaW1wbGVUeXBlEAQICDEyMzQ1Njc4BAgICAUBAAAAAQ==
```

Ok, this is weird. It works, but it throws an error.

```
1..1
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2/SOAP/WSDL/XSD/Typelib/Builtin/anySimpleType.pm line 53, <DATA> chunk 1.
ok 1 - foo
```

So I looked at [line 53 of anySimpleType.pm](https://metacpan.org/source/MKUTTER/SOAP-WSDL-2.00.10/lib/SOAP/WSDL/XSD/Typelib/Builtin/anySimpleType.pm#L53), and it says:

```
my $OBJECT_CACHE_REF = Class::Std::Fast::OBJECT_CACHE_REF();

sub new {
    my $self = pop @{ $OBJECT_CACHE_REF->{ $_[0] } }; # <-- here
    $self = bless \(my $o = Class::Std::Fast::ID()), $_[0]
        if not defined $self;
```

Hmm. `$_[0]` is undef. Looks like `new` was called without an argument.

But how the hell can loading Test::MockObject do that? Or maybe that warning is always popping up, but somehow it was not shown before? I debugged it a little, and it turns out the warning is always showing in Komodo IDEs debugger, regardless of what I loaded.

However, it only shows up in the normal program output if I have Test::MockObject loaded as well. Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: I tried to recreate your issue but it is working in perl 5.10. I had to regenerate the base64 hash, it was not worked in my config:
Byte order is not compatible at ../../lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into ../../lib/auto/Storable/thaw.al) line 415, <DATA> chunk 1, at ./test_mockobject_new.pl line 22

Comment: It seems it is always throwing these errors silently, but somehow the version of MockObject I have unsilences it. I can use `local $SIG{__WARN__}` to filter these warnings out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this is happening exactly. My debugging led me to believe that the initialization warnings are always thrown by these Storable objects. However, they are silent if Test::MockObject is not there.

So the workaround to get it to shut up is as follows:

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { warn $_[0] unless $_[0] =~ /uninitialized/};
local $/ = undef;
my $object = Storable::thaw(decode_base64(<DATA>));
ok( $object->get_value, 'foo' );
```